# Update MOTD at ssh login on Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, motd

What's the most clean way to display a different quote from a file (line-seperated) as MOTD on every SSH login on Debian?

In other words, how can I trigger a MOTD update on SSH login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question because I found a way to do this and forgot about this question.

What I did:

Created a file called `ssh_login_quote.sh`in my user's home folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `shuf -n 1 quotes.txt`
```

(Don't forget to `chmod +x ssh_login_quote.sh`)

Then created a file in the same directory called `quotes.txt` with one quote per line.

In `~/.profile` I added `~/./ssh_login_quote.sh` to the end of the file.

`exit` and `ssh` back in (or reopen your terminal) and you should see your random quote!

Comment: The downside for this is that it only works for that one user.

Comment: @Jenny D very true. In my case it wasn't a problem, although I can imagine Linux has some sort of "global" Bash profile, which could be used. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Most, if not all, unixes have a global profile. It's usually called `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing this is not on .profile or .bashrc, but in MOTD

When you login, pam_motd module of PAM will print the message of the day.

1. create `/etc/update-motd.d`
2. create a script `/etc/update-motd.d/00name` with this contents

   echo; echo `shuf -n 1 quotes.txt`

MOTD for you will now consist of `/etc/motd` if it exists concatenated to your random line `/etc/motd.dynamic`.

See details here

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/

Comment: The link you provide in your answer is the clearest explanation I've seen. You should be writing Debian's [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/motd)! Debian's [`pam_motd`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libpam-modules/pam_motd.8.en.html) is clear enough, but the wiki fails to "bring it all together" IMHO. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

The most common method is to use `fortune` from /etc/.profile. However, that file assumes that the quotes should contain linebreaks and be separated by a line containing only the charater `%`.

To convert your quotefile to a proper fortune file format:

```
sed -e s/$/"\n"%/ /path/to/quote/file > /path/to/quote/fortune
strfile /path/to/quote/fortune /path/to/quote/fortune.dat
```

Verify that it works by running

```
fortune /path/to/quote/
```

Add into `/etc/profile`:

```
fortune /path/to/fortune
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found another way to do it (which may or may not be a bit less clever) which does the job. I'll add it as my own answer in a minute.